# iOS MVVM using Combine with Input/Outut pattern in UIKit

Tags: ios, mvvm, binding, uikit, combine

I'm trying to make an app using Combine with UIKit. and I want to implement MVVM architecture with Input/Output pattern

If something happens in the View/ViewController (like view life cycle events or button tapped etc..) it should trigger the API request and View/ViewController react these responses

This is my code below

*`ViewModelType` protocol*

```
protocol ViewModelType {
    associatedtype Input
    associatedtype Output
    
    var input: Input { get }
    var output: Output { get }
}
```

*`Response` model*

```
struct Response {
    let text: String?
}
```

*`ViewMode` class*

```
class ViewModel: ViewModelType {
    struct Input {
        let buttonDidTapped: PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>
    }
    
    struct Output {
        let text: AnyPublisher<String?, Never>
    }
    
    let input: Input
    let output: Output
    
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        
        let buttonDidTappedSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
        
        let response = buttonDidTappedSubject.map { $0 }.flatMap(ViewModel.fetch).eraseToAnyPublisher() // ---- 1
        let text = response.map { $0?.text } // ---- 2
            
        input = Input(buttonDidTapped: buttonDidTappedSubject)
        output = Output(text: text) // ---> Error! 
    }
    
    private static func fetch() -> AnyPublisher<Response?, Never> {
        return Future<Response?, Never> { promise in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                promise(.success(Response(text: "Hello World")))
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

I tried to write every Combine's code chaining in ViewModel's `init` method. Let me explain code above

1. mapping button tapped to trigger API request
2. mapping response to Output

but `text` type is not `AnyPublisher<String?, Never>`. it looks weird

`Publishers.Map<AnyPublisher<Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<Response?, Never>, Publishers.Map<PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>, ()>>.Output, Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<Response?, Never>, Publishers.Map<PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>, ()>>.Failure>, String?>`

What's wrong with my code and how can I make Input/Output pattern using Combine and UIKit

Comment: `ViewModel.Output` expects an `AnyPublisher` publisher... so you need to match the type: `Output(text: text.eraseToAnyPublisher)`

Comment: Thanks! it works. I don't know why I miss that point

Answer (score 0):

You have to erase the type using `eraseToAnyPublisher()` operator.

```
...
let text = response.map { $0?.text }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
...
output = Output(text: text)
```